# NaN loss and NaN accuracy while fitting data with 4 continuous data features and 1 numerical data prediction with LSTM

Tags: keras, deep-learning, neural-network, lstm, nan

Data looks like this (with 4 input features):

```
18655.65    18752.65    18638.00    42634653.0
```

And has a continuous output like this: 18734.85

The `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test` shapes are as follows:

> ```
> (1551, 4, 1)
> (388, 4, 1)
> (1551, 1)
> (388, 1)
> ```

This is the model below that I'm using, but the accuracy and val_accuracy are both NaN in all epochs.

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]), return_sequences=False, activation='relu'))    
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu')) 
model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics = ['accuracy']) 
model.summary()

model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=100, batch_size=128)
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/100 13/13 [==============================] - 0s 23ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy:
0.0000e+00
```

What should I try to do to make the model gives the correct output?